# Issue with calling method a second time after switching view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, viewcontroller, uialertcontroller

Ok. So I'm working on a game in sprite kit using objective C. I have a method that I call that uses the viewcontroller the skscene is running from to call a uialertcontroller at game over. Upon pressing the ok button in the alert view, I modal back to the main menu view controller. This works fine. However when I go to play the game again, switching back to the gameviewcontroller and get another game over, the uialertview fails to trigger. I get an error message saying:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x14205d600> on <GameViewController: 0x141e176f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Here is the code where I call the UIAlertController:

```
UIAlertController * gameOverAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"Game Over!" message: textscore preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

//add the button that will take us back to the main menu
UIAlertAction *okButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
    [UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToTheMenuNotFuture" sender:self];
}];

[gameOverAlert addAction: okButton];


[UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController presentViewController: gameOverAlert animated:true completion: nil];
```

Here is the code for when I modal to the gameviewcontroller:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"gotoPlay"]){
        gameController = (GameViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        gameController.playingMusic = musicHave;

    }

}
```

As I said, this work fine the first game, but when you go to play again and lose a second time, that's when the error happens.

Comment: Sounds to me like  your old view controller also exists. 1) avoid using `UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController`  use the local view controller that your gamescene is on. 2) check that you do not have a retain cycle, and that the only view controllers in your tree are those that you want to see, and no other duplicates.  The easiest way to do that is to override the deinit portion and do an NSLog

Comment: Can you explain to me HOW to use the local viewcontroller? Because thats exactly what I want to do, either that or how to remove the previous viewcontroller so that there is only one instance of the object running at any one time. I figured out that that was the the issue but I’m uncertain on how to fix it.

Comment: In your viewcontroller you are creating the scene, just create a variable in scene to retain that info

Comment: But if I created a viewcontroller variable within the skscene, that viewcontroller would still not be present in the window hierarchy. Could you give me an example of what you mean please?

Comment: You create a pointer to view controller, not a new object.   You should have a view controller class that is presenting your scene the first time,  you just say scene.viewController = self.  Or in your view controller, create a static instance variable and call ViewController.instance

Comment: None of these work. There is no .viewcontroller property for skview and I cant create an instance variable of the  gameviewcontroller in the menucontroller because even though I have imported the controller in the header I cant create a static variable of it in the same file

Comment: You are not listening to me,  I am trying to teach you.  You need to MAKE viewController property on your scene so that you can set it in your view controller

Comment: I can understand that. However due to how the scene is defined in the gameviewcontroller I am unable to pass any variables to it so I don’t see how I can implement that idea.

Comment: ..... huh?  the only way you can get a scene onto a view is through the view controller in some way.  There is no magic.  You have a view controller class, it is calling something like `GameScene *scene = [[GameScene alloc] init]; ` you just need to add scene.viewController = self before [view presentScene:scene]

Comment: But thats not how the skscene is initiated. I’m typing off my phone but I’ll attempt to write the code here. By the way, i have solved this problem if you can see the answer.

Comment: SKScene *scene = [gamescene scenewithsize: skview.bounds.size];  this means that you cant alter any gamescene variables because the scene is considered by the gameviewcontroller to be simply an instance of skscene not gamescene. I cant access gamescene variables defined in its header

Comment: Yes you can, you are using the wrong pointer declaration, dont use SKScene* use GameScene*

Comment: Thanks I’ll keep that in mind if I need to change something else later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

(isDismissed is an int value starting off as 0)

```
//add the button that will take us back to the main menu
UIAlertAction *okButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
    isDismissed = 1;
    [UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToTheMenuNotFuture" sender:self];

}];

[gameOverAlert addAction: okButton];


[UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController presentViewController: gameOverAlert animated:true completion: nil];
if(isDismissed == 1){
    [UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion: nil];
    [UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController presentViewController: gameOverAlert animated:true completion: nil];
    [UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToTheMenuNotFuture" sender:self];
}
```

}

So the issue here as in the comments is that there were multiple gameviewcontroller instances running at once. The code above dismisses the 'current' gameviewcontroller and then attempts to run what I want to the original one. It works, however I am unsure of whether or not the game is then deallocating the old gameviewcontroller or creating yet more duplicates every time it runs. In the end I see it as this. If it is deallocating like it should then its fine. If its not, then the game which I'd say consumes about 8MB of RAM would eventually cause the iPhone to lag. If this does happen then you have obviously been playing it for so long that you should really take a break from it anyway. Its not a bug, its a feature!